# SSD Lifetime vs HDD lifetime

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I never used a SSD .

But reading so many articles about SSd performance , i'm thinking to change my HDD and to get a SSD.

But i've read that the SSD's lifetime is short comparing to a HDD.

My actual HDD ( Western digital Black ) has work more than 7 years ( intensive work almost every day) without any defect.

Is there any approximate lifetime for a SSD , and what's happen with stored data when a SSD lifetime is over ?

Thank you !

Comment: What i've found i wrote on my post. I've found that SSD lifetime is too short comparing with HDD. But i think on internet there are too many articles and  not all have true information. For what i've made this question here , because i think  this is a professional site.

Comment: In that case, try to format your question to be one question, and hopefully it will be unique enough not to be removed.

Comment: Data point:  A SSD hosting multiple virtual machines, it was previously a system drive:  1 yr/8 mo work time, 98% of life remaining.  These days they don't burn out under reasonable loads.  (Using one as a cache for spinning rust is another matter--you certainly can burn them out that way.)

Comment: How long a SSD is expected to last, is detailed in the specifications of the SSD, and dependent on the quality and type of the memory being used.  There is no "general" lifetime estimate that exists for SSDs they all vary based on the make and model, all SSDs, indicate the expected lifetime writes though.

Comment: I'm reading the specifications for a SSD (Samsung EVO 850 1TB )  : Endurance  1.75M hrs MTBF. This means around 200 years !!!!!

Comment: That is time to hardware failure (averaged). Acutal time for a SSD to degrade (performance and reliability case) varies but is usually exceeds a decade or two.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://www.zdnet.com/article/ssd-reliability-in-the-real-world-googles-experience/) is a recent article on Google's experience with SSDs.  It was based on:

> - Millions of drive days over 6 years
> - 10 different drive models
> - 3 different flash types: MLC, eMLC and SLC
> - Enterprise and consumer drives
>
> Key conclusions
>
> - Ignore Uncorrectable Bit Error Rate (UBER) specs. A meaningless number.
> - Good news: Raw Bit Error Rate (RBER) increases slower than expected from wearout and is not correlated with UBER or other failures.
> - High-end SLC drives are no more reliable that MLC drives.
> - Bad news: SSDs fail at a lower rate than disks, but UBER rate is higher.
> - SSD age, not usage, affects reliability.
> - Bad blocks in new SSDs are common, and drives with a large number of bad blocks are much more likely to lose hundreds of other blocks, most likely due to die or chip failure.
> - 30-80 percent of SSDs develop at least one bad block and 2-7 percent develop at least one bad chip in the first four years of deployment.
> - SSD UBER rates are higher than disk rates, which means that backing up SSDs is even more important than it is with disks. The SSD is less likely to fail during its normal life, but more likely to lose data.

Comment: Thank you , reading that article ( if all is true )  make me thinking again if i want to switch to SSD.

Comment: Yes, it makes me think twice as well.

Comment: External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.

Comment: There's a thing that i don't understand : This question has been responded , and the response has get a Up vote. But the question itself has 2 down votes. So a very bad Question that has a good response. !!!???

Comment: @Ferdi: People evaluate each posting on its own merits.  As of now, your question has 2 upvotes and 3 downvotes, so there's obviously differences of opinion, or people weigh the positives and negatives differently, or people thought poorly of the question until this answer was posted that provides a different perspective.  A good answer can help to clarify a question or demonstrate its value.  I think that's the case here.

Answer (score -1):

This was asked 2 years ago and a good chance that you have already found out.
But here is for everyone else.
If you move around alot with a laptop, and travel alot with it the SSD has a longer lifespan since the HDD has moving parts and a SSD don't. SSDs are much faster, but they are also more expensive.

Comment: do you have any source for that? as it is, it sounds like an opinion.

Comment: well completely depends how you use it, I should have added that. If you have a laptop and move around alot, the SSD have a greater lifespan.